# jQuery - фильтр метода запроса

Tags: jquery

Имеются несколько разных форм в `html` с методом `POST` или `GET`, как заставить `jQuery`, отлавливать каким методом был отправлен запрос и заменять `type: 'POST',` на нужный.

```js
$(function ($) {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var frm = $(this).parents('form');
        var script = $(this).parents('form').data("script");
        $.ajax({
            url: './' + script,
            data: $(frm).serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $(".response-field").text(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $(".response-field").text(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
    <!-- POST метод -->
    <form data-script="record_status">
        <button type="button">record status</button>
    </form>

    <!-- GET метод -->
    <form data-script="system">
        <h2>system info</h2>
        <input type="text" id="_model" name="_model" placeholder="_model">
        <input type="text" id="_hostname" name="_hostname" placeholder="_hostname">
        <input type="text" id="_firmware" name="_firmware" placeholder="_firmware">
        <input type="text" id="_version" name="_version" placeholder="_version">
        <input type="text" id="_hardware" name="_hardware" placeholder="_hardware">
        <input type="text" id="_linux" name="_linux" placeholder="_linux">
        <input type="text" id="_systemUptime" name="_systemUptime" placeholder="_systemUptime">
        <input type="text" id="_uptime" name="_uptime" placeholder="_uptime">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался таким методом.

```
$(function ($) {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var frm = $(this).parents('form');
        var script = $(this).parents('form').data("script");
        if (frm.hasClass('post')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: './' + script,
                data: $(frm).serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',

                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $(".response-field").html(response);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    $(".response-field").html(error);
                }
            });
        }
        else if (frm.hasClass('get')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: './' + script,
                data: $(frm).serialize(),
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',

                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $(".response-field").html(response);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    $(".response-field").html(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант можно так: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxWZxr

Подписываешься на событие отправки (submit) у `<form>`, а в обработчике event имеет свойство `currentTarget`, он в свою очередь имеет свойство `method`

Comment: ответ может быть и хорош, но мои знания jQuery... ограничиваются почти тем, что я знаю для чего он :(

Comment: дак у меня готовый код почти для твоей задачи. Если ты его даже просто вставишь, у тебя на всех кнопках submit внутри `form` будет все работать

Comment: на примере разметки - нет `submit` - и обработчик написан для click.

Comment: у него все находится в тегах `form`, я не думаю что сложно дописать тип `submit`, для того, чтобы код работал)

Comment: стоит добавить пример кода, с указанием отличий. непосредственно в ответ, а не только ссылкой